# C++ Function is not returning a value

Tags: visual-c++

here is my code, I can not figure out why it won't work as a function when  the exact code in main() produces the correct answer.  The assignment is to   convert binary number to decimal.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
using namespace std;
int binaryCon(int biNum);
int main()
{
    int num, bin, Bnum;
    cout << "Enter the binary number(1s and 0s) : ";
    cin >> num;
    bin = num;
    Bnum = binaryCon(num);
    cout << "The decimal equivalent of " << bin << " : " << Bnum << endl;
}
    int binaryCon(int biNum)
{
    long dec = 0, rem = 0, base = 1;
    enter code here`while (biNum > 0)
    rem = biNum % 10;
    dec = dec + rem * base;
    base = base * 2;
    biNum = biNum / 10;

    return biNum;
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with visual-c++ but my guess is you need to move binaryCon() before than main() function.

Comment: @TimeString there is a forward declaration, so that is not the problem. The problem is in the code.

Comment: Something it should return. what value it is returning? you are not using `{` `}` in your while loop. bcz of that its looping infinite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

corrected code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int binaryCon(int biNum);
int main()
{
    int num, bin, Bnum;
    cout << "Enter the binary number(1s and 0s) : ";
    cin >> num;
    bin = num;
    Bnum = binaryCon(num);
    cout << "The decimal equivalent of " << bin << " : " << Bnum << endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
int binaryCon(int biNum)
{
    long dec = 0, rem = 0, base = 1;
    while (biNum > 0){
        rem = biNum % 10;
        dec = dec + rem * base;
        base = base * 2;
        biNum = biNum / 10;
    }
    return dec;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are not using `{` and `}` in your while loop may be its going in infinite loop. As its working for this line only

```
while (biNum > 0)
    rem = biNum % 10;    // running this line infinite as `biNum > 0`
```

Use

```
while (biNum > 0){
    rem = biNum % 10;
    dec = dec + rem * base;
    base = base * 2;
    biNum = biNum / 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this?

```
while (biNum > 0)
{
    rem = biNum % 10;
    dec = dec + rem * base;
    base = base * 2;
    biNum = biNum / 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

int main() or int main(int argc, char** argv) must return a value. If you return 0 then it means that there is no problem with code. Another numbers 1,2 etc means there is an error.(Returned numbers are error numbers)